# how to change hierarchical taxonomy path using Pathauto

Tags: path-aliases, taxonomy-terms

i have posted it on drupal forum also  but there was no answer. Here is that:

> i am really working hard to know how i can add sub-categories in drupal 7. so i want to change the path of parent terms taxonomy path like this way:
>   Category 1 - Path should be: mysite.com/category/Category 1
>   - sub category 1 - Path should be: mysite.com/category/Category 1/sub category 1
>   - sub category 2 - Path should be: mysite.com/category/Category 1/sub category 2
>   Category 2 - Path should be: mysite.com/category/Category 2
>   - sub category 1 - Path should be: mysite.com/category/Category 2/sub category 1
>   - sub category 2 - Path should be: mysite.com/category/Category 2/sub category 2
>   i think this can be done with URL aliases > PATTERNS
>   but as a beginner i am really confused how to do. So, some one please help as can be described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern works for me at admin/config/search/path/patterns:

[term:vocabulary]/[term:parent:parents-all]/[term:name]

Comment: ok, i have a taxonomy called "Products Category" so is that i should write it on "Pattern for all Products Category paths" field. you may see the sceenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zDWwv.png , cause i want to apply this for only "Products Category" taxonomy thanks

Comment: that would be the right place. However, [term:vocabulary] will probably create "products-category". If you don't want that, you can type that part in manually, such as: products/[term:parent:parents-all]/[term:name]

Comment: thanks keva works nice, one more question: suppose i have a category called "Agriculture > Rice" so if someone choose "Rice" under "Agriculture" then it shows only "Rice" as the product category in the content page. But is there any way to show main category then sub category, like this: `Product Category: Agriculture>Rice` thanks again

Comment: This module looks like it might do that: http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter. If not, you might consider http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb_lite

Comment: okay, i know about breadcrumb ,, but i want to do something like this => See the image (number 1) showing how the taxonomy is showing in my site and (number 2) showing how i wanted to show taxonomies in my site. Image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4L215.png any idea? Thanks

Comment: I haven't actually implemented that, so don't have an answer ... but did you try drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter ? The description sounded like what you want.

Comment: but it has the same result

Comment: hellow, one more question what then if i have 4 or 5 terms in a taxonomy. So in this case how to configure the path url?

Comment: I would open up a new SE question about this.

Answer (score 3):

this work for me:

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:parents:join-path]/[term:name]
```

this pattern generates the path: **Category-Name/Category-1/sub-category-1/Term-Name**

Comment: This worked perfectly. `[term:parent:parents-all]` (as in the accepted answer) collapses the elements of the path into a new hyphenated term.